# Every PDF page to new canvas using PDF.js

Tags: jquery, loops, pdf, canvas, pdf.js

please help me with this.
I trying to create for every page from pdf single canvas and show page.
If I click this button more times it creates every pages ok. But if I use loop it works bad. Here is example where it works for multiple clicking on button:

```
var currentPage = 0;
$(".btn-create").click( function(){

    inputScale = $(".input-scale").val();
    documentURL = $(".documenturl").val();

    var numPages = 0;
    var thePDF = null;

    PDFJS.getDocument(documentURL).then(function(pdf) {

        thePDF = pdf;
        numPages = pdf.numPages;

    });

        currentPage++;

        $(".workspace").append("<canvas id='the-canvas"+currentPage+"'></canvas>");

        PDFJS.getDocument(documentURL).then(function(pdf) {

            pdf.getPage(currentPage).then(function(page) {
                var scale = inputScale;
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'+currentPage);
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                page.render(renderContext);

            });
        });
});
```

But if I use this with loop it create just last deformated page.

```
var currentPage = 0;
$(".btn-create").click( function(){

    for ( var i = 1; i < 4; i++ ) {

       // SAME CODE AS IN PREVIOUS BUTTON 

    }

});
```

Thank you for every help.
Kasta

Comment: Hard to tell without complete code, but looks like you a making basic js mistake -- using variables within functions defined in the for-loop. See http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#62 and #63 for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this in one of my apps currently:

```
PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(
  function getPdf(pdf) {

  // Set number of pages to repeat canvas elements
  $scope.numPages = pdf.numPages;

  var getPages = function(pageCount){
      var pagePromises = [];
      if (pageCount > 0){
        for (var q = 0; q < pageCount; q++) {
            pages.push({});
        }
        $scope.pages = pages;
        _.each(pages, function(page, i){
            pdf.getPage(i+1).then(function getPage(page) {
              var scale = 1;
              var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

              // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
              // Each canvas element must have a unique id
              var canvasId = '' + 'someUniqueIdentifer';


              var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);

              var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

              canvas.height = viewport.height;
              canvas.width = viewport.width;
              // $log.debug('PDF canvas: ', canvas);
              //
              // Render PDF page into canvas context
              //
              var pageRendering = page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});

              // Using a callback to do stuff before render
              var completeCallback = pageRendering.internalRenderTask.callback;
              pageRendering.internalRenderTask.callback = function (error) {
                    //Step 1; What you want to do before calling the complete method         
                    //Step 2: Call it       
                    completeCallback.call(this, error);
                    //Step 3: do some more stuff
              };
            });
        });
      }
  };
});
```

It's using Angular to handle the repeating and id generation for the canvas elements, but doing the same in JQuery should be trivial.